# Computer restarts while using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-management-studio

I have Windows 7 Enterprise edition and I have installed Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Whenever I start Visual Studio to work on my project the computer restarts with no error message. I tried to run Visual Studio as an administrator, but still my PC gets restarted and I lose my work!

Is it related to the memory size or to the Windows version?

i checked the window application log i found Error

> The description for Event ID 0 from source MSOIDSVC.EXE cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> InitializeSvcAPI failed with hr = 0x80048883

i don't know what is the meaning of this error.
also i found another error message

> Can't find script engine "VBSript" for script
> \servername\SysVol\servername\Policies{C914....}\User\Scripts\Logon\Acrobat_7_Log.vbs"

any idea

My system details.

[image: S]

Comment: Press your start menu and type in **compmgmt.msc**, then hit enter. In there you want to click even viewer, and then either windows or applications and services logs and see if there shouldn't be one with a warning or error sign on it.

Comment: Please edit your question with the information if you found in the event viewer, or close this question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory size or the version of Windows your using.  The errors are pretty clear.  You have system files that are corrupt that Visual Studio requires.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, what are these files and where can find them and how to fix these issues? note that i have another PC with windows 8 and i am not facing any issues with visual studio and SQL, is it a bug in window 7?

Comment: check the event log for Kernel ID 41 entries: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504/en-us

Comment: i was able to read the dump file, and i am getting this error >ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igdkmd64.sys
Probably caused by : igdkmd64.sys ( igdkmd64+23cb0 )

Comment: igdkmd64.sys = Intel HD driver. So update the GPU driver or disable the HW acceleration inside the Visual Studio options.

Comment: @magicandre1981 can you please change your comment to an answer to accept it, thank you

Comment: @NooraNo ok, I've done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windbg output

```
ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igdkmd64.sys 
Probably caused by : igdkmd64.sys ( igdkmd64+23cb0 )
```

indicates that the reboot was caused by the Intel HD graphic driver. Go to intel.com, download and install the latest driver version or [disable the hardware acceleration inside Visual Studio options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215/).

[image]